# How is it possible to get doctrine entities from a query builder in a 2D array?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I created a query, with multiple entities selected:

```
$qb->select(['user', 'unit'])
```

If I call `$qb->getQuery()->getResult()`, I get an array, like this:

```
[ Entity\User, Entity\Unit, Entity\User, Entity\Unit, ... ]
```

But I would like to get the result in this format:

```
[ [ Entity\User, Entity\Unit ], [ Entity\User, Entity\Unit ], ... ]
```

How is it possible?
I was not able to find anything in the [doctrine Query documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-phpcr-odm/en/latest/reference/query.html)

---

I could use `array_chunk($result, 2)`, but I am not sure that it will work in all cases. For example what if one `unit` is null. Doctrine skips it, or it just inserts a null into the list? I am not able to find detailed information about the `getResult` function.

Comment: Show full query builder. Under what logic should `User` and `Unit` be grouped into arrays of size 2?

Comment: Each user has one ( or zero ) unit. That is a nullable manyToOne relationship

Comment: Why do you want to get the User and Unit entities separately? Assuming the relationship is defined correctly, you can just select User and use a getter to return the related Unit.

Comment: Assume, that there is no bi-directional relationship between the two

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "user" and "unit" has no direct relationship or need to be fetched entirely together then you should group them using a custom class handler